# Should I show mark boundaries on academic CV?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv

I am writing an academic CV for PhD applications. I have included the marks for each exam I did in my final year.

The marking scheme is slightly unusual: the threshold for the highest mark was 59 (normally around 70). I got (~10 marks) higher than 59 in a few papers and I want it to be clear that I was above the boundary, should I mention in the CV that the boundary was 59?

Comment: If you got the highest mark (A?), why can't you just put that down?

Comment: @Sverre I thought you were supposed to put the exact marks. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mark", since you seem to be using it for two different things: (1) Grades (e.g. A, B) (2) Scores (points, percentages, etc.). I've never seen a CV that lists scores for exams.

Comment: @Sverre apologies. I meant exact score, i.e a percentage. I’ll take it that your advice is just to leave off the scores then.

Comment: Most CVs do not contain a list of grades, but sometimes such list are asked for separately. But it is *your* CV so you can do what you want. There are no rules. If you like to emphasize how good your scores were you can put them in as long as you explain clearly what the scores mean: you correctly identified that others may not understand the scoring system, so if you decide to show your scores you have to make sure they do.

Answer (score 2):

If the exams are listed in your transcript, then you do not need to repeat them in your CV. The reason is that they'll be better (and officially) explained on your transcript.

Answer (score 0):

Some Universities use a "percentile" parameter to show your grade respect to the rest of students. Maybe you can ask for this metric or if possible calculate it by yourself.